# Disable and Enable Wifi Connection

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, microsoft-outlook, powershell

Once in a while, Outlook isn't able to access the network to get new mail and if I disable and enable the WiFi connection, Outlook is able to get new mail.

I would like to write a script to do this and tried using PowerShell's `Disable-NetAdapter`, but it looks like the name of the adapter has some unprintable characters in its beginning, which I can see if I use `Get-NetAdapter`, but can't enter them in a command.

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It is more likely Outlook is just going offline (not a function of wireless).  Make sure Outlook Work Offline (Send / Receive Tab) has not be set and perhaps also try a Full Repair of Office.

Comment: you can send the output of a `Get-` to the matching `Set-` cmdlet. [*grin*] that will get around the "can't enter that text" problem. ///// also, most cmdlets accept wildcard chars in parameters like `-Name`.

Comment: Does this problem occur on the Outlook desktop client?  If so, in order to further confirm whether the problem is related to the network, it is recommended that you try to log in on Web mail and test whether your mailbox can be connected normally. You can also see whether other programs that need to run online can run normally under the same network.

Comment: I managed to create a powershell script that disables and enables the interface using the InterfaceDescription property of the interface instead of it's name.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach, where the name of your network is an SSID consisting of alphanumerics and possibly hyphens:

```
netsh wlan disconnect interface="Wi-Fi"
netsh wlan connect name="YourNetwork"
```

Comment: I had the same problem there. If I issue the command netsh wlan show interfaces I see ??Wi-Fi as the interface name.

Comment: Have you tried using single quotes?  '??Wi-Fi'